# Calculating moving average using previous record as a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to calculate a moving average for a column, that requires an arithmetic calculation using parameters from the previous record.

I have records for a meter reading X, with dates, I want to perform a calculation
to determine the average rate, using formula

```
(reading x - reading y)/(reading date @ x - reading date @ y)
```

Where Y is always the meter reading from the previous record. The DATEDIFF is in days.

```
  Meter | Reading |    Date
 -------+---------+------------
    1   |  39,000 | 1 Jan 2016
    1   |  39,200 | 1 Feb 2016
    1   |  39,300 | 1 Mar 2016
```

I would like an additional column that inserts the calculated field, 
it would have to read from the latest record, and process backwards - 
since I have 2 years of readings, and not the first.

```
Meter | Reading |     Date   |      Rate
------+---------+------------+--------------------
  1   |  39,000 | 1 Aug 2016 | (200 / 31) = 6.45
  1   |  39,200 | 1 Sep 2016 | (100 / 30) = 3.33
  1   |  39,300 | 1 Oct 2016 | Z
```

I want to select this into a table for reporting.

-- EDIT --

**I was getting Divide by 0 errors and decided to calculate the Reading X - Reading Y seperately as ReadingDiff.**

`LEAD(MeterReading, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY MeterID ORDER BY MeterReading) - MeterReading AS MeterDiff`

Because there are more than 1 MeterIDs in the select list, how would i prevent it from calculating a MeterDiff between the last record of MeterID 1 and the first record of MeterID 2 ? Can I not set the first record for each MeterID to 0 ?

Comment: Your tag `tsql` points to `sql-server`, but which version?

Comment: @Shnugo - I am using 2012 and 2014.  I believe i could use window frame functions ?

Answer (score 4):

It would be something like this:

```
select t.*,
       ( (reading - lag(reading) over (partition by meter order by date)) /
         nullif(datediff(day, lag(date) over (partition by meter order by date), date), 0)
       )
from t;
```

If reading is an integer, then be careful, because SQL Server does integer division.  So, you might want:

```
select t.*,
       ( (1.0*reading - lag(reading) over (partition by meter order by date)) /
         nullif(datediff(day, lag(date) over (partition by meter order by date), date), 0)
       )
from t;
```

Note:  `lag()` is ANSI standard functionality implemented in SQL Server since version 2012.  Prior to that, you would need to use a more computationally intensive method, such as `outer apply`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this was what i was looking for.

Comment: I was getting Divide by 0 errors and decided to calculate the Reading X - Reading Y seperately as ReadingDiff.

LEAD(MeterReading, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY MeterID ORDER BY MeterReading) - MeterReading AS MeterDiff

Because there are more than 1 MeterIDs in the select list, how would i prevent it from calculating a MeterDiff between the last record of MeterID 1 and the first record of MeterID 2 ?

Can I not set the first record for each MeterID to 0 ?

Comment: @IvanNel . . . `NULLIF()` is the easiest way to avoid divide-by-zero.  You can use `COALESCE()` to set the first value to 0.